# Not able to detect Input from Barcode or Keyboard. Angular 2+

Tags: angular

I have an input box that a user can scan (handheld scanner) or manually enter(keyboard) a UPC. If the user scans the UPC, I would like to automatically call a search function, but if manually entered, the user will have to hit a search button. I have been able to find solutions for angularJS and jquery however nothing for angular 2+

Comment: Have you tried `<input (change)="myFunc($event)"/>`?

Comment: Yes i have tried...it is not working, same as Keypress... but i need keypress for Barcode scanning and for input from keyboard i want to submit with submit button, not by keypress.